Who is the monologue targeted at at the end of White Tiger?
The movie White Tiger (2012) ends with a monologue by Adolf Hitler. This scene leaves many unanswered questions, but the one I'm interested in is, who is the person he's talking to?

If the character\person cannot be identified, who is the actor playing the listener?

Good question. Some reviews say he's a journalist; As for his exact identity, well, that's a toughie.

@Walt I found two theories on the internet, one suggested that the listener might be Martin Heidgger (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Martin_Heidegger). The other theory suggested the listener is satan... and taking into account the whole movie it's actually possible. However those are just theories and I was hoping that the director left some clues at who that person might be.

Just my point of view of course but I feel the silent character at the end symbolized evil personified. Why? Well, Hitler states at the beginning of his monolog 

"We have know each other too well for too long. Too much ties us together for me to hide my thoughts from you"

I am more than certain that he is not speaking to any journalist. Given that the person was dressed quite elegantly and was sitting in a very poise posture with hand on chin as if intrigued by what Hitler was saying. I believe he was speaking to either Death, demon or even the Devil himself incarnate. If you look around in the room there are a lot of clues. The decor I feel was goth for that era. For one the seat that Hitler was sitting in. The back of the chair had some sort of devil faced engraving. On the back wall there was a white head with what appeared to two horns. Also the massive mural on the wall that seemed to depict a scene out of Dante's Inferno. 
Lastly, Hitler allegedly committed suicide on April 30 1945 in a bunker with his wife Eva Braun if I am not mistaken. The Germans surrendered on May 7 1945. So this conversation may have actually taken place post death in Hell with the Prince of Darkness. :) Yes, I know. I have a vivid imagination. Just my perspective.I am sure there are plenty of other versions of just who the mysterious stranger was. :) lol! 

Any source to backup your imagination.

The first time I watched this scene, I instantly concluded that Hitler is talking to Lucifer/The Devil Himself, so I agree completely with the post above. Employing my imagination, I think the scene depicts the Devil debriefing one of his most trusted lieutenants after completion of a mission on earth. I don't think Hitler is going to suffer eternal torture and punishment in Hell. To the contrary, as one of the Devil's most trusted lieutenants, he is going to be sent back to earth for another mission. As Bertolt Brecht said, "Do not rejoice too much that Hitler is dead and gone because the bitch who bore him is in heat again."
